# Equal LI widths fill 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make each LI equal width and fill 100% of the width on Bootstrap tabs.

I have been reading that you need to have

```
ul{display:table}
li{display:table-cell}
```

But this just isn't working for me, i am not sure if it is Bootstrap that is causing this or not. But i need to be able to accommodate 3 - 5 tabs depending on the product page.

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xQ8Q8/1/ to shows what i am trying to do.

Comment: Try removing the `li` float.

Comment: Wow thanks for that it worked perfectly! i could have sworn that i tried that... if you wanna submit that as an answer i would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Done, I added the corrections needed to maintain the correct `ul` height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `float: left` defined in `.nav-tabs > li`. Set `float: none` in your CSS to override that behavior:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
}
```

Now you have to correct the `UL` height:

```
#productReviewTab {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 31px; // Just to maintain your initial height
}
```

Yes, I removed the height property, you could set it to `44px` if you want. For what I test, is the same.